# Check if RTSP Stream has finished

Tags: c++, sockets, stream, udp, rtsp

first I'm gonna try to explain what exactly I want to do:

I have an IP Camera which has a circular buffer from which I want to read the data. The communication between camera and my application takes place over RTSP, which means I have a TCP connection to the camera. 
The camera itself is capable of streaming the data over RTP.

Now the important part is, that when the camera starts streaming it's stuff, my application shall **NOT** read back the data. There is some kind of passive datalogger in the network which is responsible for recording the data.

The problem is, that as long as the camera is streaming, the Socket from my application needs to be opened, otherwise the camera will stop streaming.

So lets see what I have so far:

I open a socket, which connects to the camera and then sends the needed RTSP commands `OPTIONS`, `DESCRIBE`, `SETUP` and then `PLAY`. After this my socket remains open and the camera streams.

Now here comes the difficult part:

As I already said, I **can not** parse all the UDP data. But how can I then determine when the stream has ended?  On wireshark I see that when the stream finishes I get a `RTCP` message which says `Sender Report Goodbye`.

This is the point where I would want to close my socket, but how can I determine  that the camera has finished without parsing any UDP data?

Comment: AFAIK RTP is over UDP, and events sent on RTCP which is TCP. So you *have to* read on the TCP connection...

Comment: Yeah but RTCP doesn't give me any information about the status of the stream. So any information I get from the TCP connection can't tell me if the stream is finished :/

Comment: "On wireshark I see that when the stream finishes I get a RTCP message which says Sender Report Goodbye"

Comment: Oh sorry I got confused with all the abbrevations - Yea RTCP sends that Goodbyer signal **but** RTCP is not based on TCP it is based on UDP. So this message can get lost without me getting any knowledge of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay it is possible to determine the end of the Stream.

There are two lines of communication after the Stream has started.
There is the `RTP` Stream, which contains all the raw data. Besides that there is some `RTCP` Data, which can be used to control the stream.

The important part is, that the data is sent on different Ports. These ports are defined in the `RTSP SETUP` Request. Now while the camera is streaming, the data incoming on the `RTP` can just be ignored as intended, while you can open a socket to listen on the `RTCP` port. There you get some `Sender Reports` until the stream is finished ( with a last `Sender Report Goodbye` ). If you read this message you know you can close, since the stream has finished.

Note: On some devices you may need to send some `Receiver Reports` as answer to the`Sender Reports` otherwise the stream may stop, since the device thinks the client timed out.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you want to parse the RTCP packets: it's not very difficult.

It does not make sense that the camera stops streaming once the TCP connection is closed.  According to the RTSP RFC:

> There is no notion of an RTSP connection; instead, a server maintains
>      a session labeled by an identifier. An RTSP session is in no way tied
>      to a transport-level connection such as a TCP connection. During an
>      RTSP session, an RTSP client may open and close many reliable
>      transport connections to the server to issue RTSP requests.
>      Alternatively, it may use a connectionless transport protocol such as
>      UDP.

Unless my interpretation is incorrect, the closing of the socket should not affect the media stream. You should get the manufacturer to conform to the RTSP specification.

FYI, is generally recommended that an RTSP server time out a TCP connection if no activity has taken place. AFAIR the default is 60 seconds. You can keep the connection alive by sending periodic GET_PARAMETER requests.

As a workaround, since you are doing the RTSP you know the incoming port numbers of the RTP and RTCP connections. If you don't want to parse the RTCP to look for the BYE message, you can simply discard all incoming RTP and RTCP packets and then once no packets have been received on the RTP port for x seconds, close the connection to the server.

Comment: He wants to keep `RTP`/`UDP` communication between server and external software item. He would only deal with `RTSP`. If he would be able to send an RTSP command querying status of the broadcst, it would meet the needs, but I don't think it is possible unless RTSP server has a custom extension for this.

Comment: Well you got a point there, but the part you quoted -> doesn't it state the relation between a RTSP connection and another TCP connection? What I have is a RTSP Connection to control a RTP Broadcast ( where RTP falls under UDP ). Now I really made sure the camera stops the RTP stream when my TCP ( RTSP ) Socket closes. At the moment I do it like this: I read back the cyclic RTCP messages ( the session descriptions ) until I get a "Sender Report Goodbye " - If this comes I know I can close my TCP socket. And if no Report comes for a given timeout I just close it too..

Comment: @Toby AFAIU the RTSP connection is the TCP connection. To me that means that a server should not stop streaming, if the RTSP connection is closed since the session identifier is used to maintain state. Your solution sounds like the best thing to do, glad you came right.

Comment: @Ralf Youre right, the camera should actually keep on streaming even with the Socket from the RTSP Connection closed. But since the implementation on the camera seems to think otherwise^^ I need to arrange my application with this! Well but I guess (as you said) its ok the way I do it now! Should be sufficient! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have to be on top of data sent via `RTP`/`UDP` in order to effectively detect end of broadcast, I can only think of implementing full RTSP client (with RTP part) and re-sending RTP to the address of interest. Otherwise having only RTSP control connection without seeing actual RTP data it is unlikely that you can query or otherwise obtain status of RTP data transmission, whether it is still active, or reached its end.

Answer (score 0):

As Toby stated the RtcpGoodbye packet usually indicates that the Rtp session is over.

If you need a library to parse the packets check out http://net7mma.codeplex.com/

It has a RtspClient and RtspServer implementation and works with VLC so you can use Wireshark to see how it tells client's that the show is over or just break in the code when connecting to the RtspServer with VLC.

If you need anything else let me know!